# Multiple Random Variables Independency

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let:
>
> $$f(x,y)=ce^{(-x^2-xy+y^2)/2} \qquad -\infty <x,y<\infty$$
>
> Where $c = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}$.
>
> Find the marginal densities of the variables $X$ and $Y$, then show
> that $X\sim N(0,4/3)$ and $Y\sim N(0,4/3)$.
>
> Are $X$ and $Y$ independent variables?

Ok, about that question, I know that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, because I can't write $f(x,y)=\phi(x)\psi(y)$ (is not a separable function). But I can't find the marginals because I can't solve the integrals of the definition. That integral being:
$$g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy \qquad \text{and} \qquad h(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dx$$

Any leads on how to solve that integrals to that function? Or there is another way to find the marginals? Solving that could help me showing that the marginals are normal distribuctions. Thanks.

Comment: Use the fact that $x^2+xy-y^2 = \left(x+\frac{1}{2}y\right)^2 + \frac{5}{4}y^2$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{1}{2}y\right)^2} = \sqrt{2\pi}$$

Comment: That integral is $dx$ or $dy$?

Comment: $dx$ sorry. It is the density function of the normal distribution.